# Using cloud storage for images in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage

I have been struggling with an efficient way to store and manage the pictures I need in a Ruby on Rails app I am building.  I will use a real estate app as an example:

In my real estate app I have a House model and a House controller.  On the House #show page I want to list information on the house as well as display pictures for that particular house.  Some of the houses have five pictures, others have one.  What is the best way to store these pictures and display the ones that pertain to that particular house?

Obviously I do not want to store them with the app, that would be way too bulky.  I have tried using Amazon S3 buckets and the Amazon SDK but was unable to get it up and running. Amazon's documentation is all over the place.  I currently have pictures stored in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket. They have a public link so an individual image is easy to display.  The problem lies in the fact that each house might have a different number of pictures associated with it.

Google's documentation is difficult to navigate, especially when it comes to Ruby.  If there were an easy way to access my bucket and filter the files stored there, this would be a breeze.  Any ideas?  Does anyone know how to do this in Ruby? This type of photo storage is very common and I am surprised at the difficulty I've had in getting it set up.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: One tip is use a more generic name like `Property` instead of `House` - makes a lot more sense down the line if you have lots, apartments and houses and want to share the same logic.

Comment: Thanks, Max.  That was just an example, the app has nothing to do with real estate.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is one of the best options out there, but it can be a little confusing. Try the [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for adding file associations to your models.

It gives you multiple options for how to store files and makes it easy.